# How to color the 1st row completely by black color

Tags: tables

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edEnK.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edEnK.png)How to color the 1st row completely by black color

```
       \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}ccp{2cm}p{7.5cm}}
    \toprule[.5pt]
    \rowcolor{black}
    \multirow{2}{3cm}{\centering \textbf{Regions}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Types of flower}} & \multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering \textbf{Weight}} &  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Remarks}} \\  \cline{2-3} 
    & Type I & Type I  & \\ \midrule[1pt]
    In I & DNE & DNE & abc & ddddd and ddddddddddddddd\\[.2ex]
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Above I have given a MWE... here multirow is used, but I cannot colour the full 1st row.

[image]

[image][![enter image description here]

Comment: Above I have given a MWE... here multirow is used, but I cannot colour the full 1st row.

Comment: That's not a MWE. A MWE would include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Understand, edited, Thank you

Comment: Did you test your MWE to ensure that all necessary packages are present?

Comment: I have uploaded the output

Comment: `\rowcolor` needs, e.g., `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. But IMHO currently best package for tables with colors and lines would be `tabularray`.

Comment: Edited...The problem here is that only a portion of the 1st row is coloured.. How to modify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={XccXX[2]},
      hline{2}={solid,white},
      row{odd}={bg=cyan!20},
      row{even}={bg=gray!30},
      row{1-2}={font=\bfseries,halign=c,bg=black,fg=white}
    }
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Regions & \SetCell[c=2]{} Types of flower && \SetCell[r=2]{} Weight & \SetCell[r=2]{} Remarks \\
    & Type I & Type I  & \\ 
    In I & DNE & DNE & abc & ddddd and ddddddddddddddd\\
    In I & DNE & DNE & abc & ddddd and ddddddddddddddd\\
    In I & DNE & DNE & abc & ddddd and ddddddddddddddd\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

May I suggest a layout which looks a bit more professional?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={XccXX[2]},
      hline{1,Z}={solid,1pt},
      hline{2-3}={solid},
      row{1-2}={font=\bfseries,halign=c}
    }
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Regions & \SetCell[c=2]{} Types of flower && \SetCell[r=2]{} Weight & \SetCell[r=2]{} Remarks \\
    & Type I & Type I  & \\ 
    In I & DNE & DNE & abc & ddddd and ddddddddddddddd\\
    In I & DNE & DNE & abc & ddddd and ddddddddddddddd\\
    In I & DNE & DNE & abc & ddddd and ddddddddddddddd\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works good. If I want to colour the remaining rows by cyan!30 and grey!20, can I use \rowcolor{cyan!20} and \rowcolor{gray!30}

Comment: @user1942348 No, tabularray uses its own syntax. See my updated answer

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1942348 ... but are you sure you want such a table layout? Please read https://people.inf.ethz.ch/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

Comment: Thank you, the table 2 is popularly used now-a-day...I shall go for it.. Just I have to prepare the code with my 1st row structure (without color) like my above post.

Comment: @user1942348 I added a suggestion of what I think would look better

Comment: Excellent look... I have checked but two errors are there... Missing number, treated as zero.

 
‪Gourav/test.tex, 21‬
<to be read again> 
                   Z
l.21     \end
             {tblr}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   Z
l.21     \end
             {tblr}
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

Comment: @user1942348 Is your tex distribution up-to-date? I don't get any errors from the example in my answer.

Comment: I am using overleaf

Comment: The output is attached above... the lower thick line is not coming...

Comment: In the line  hline{1,Z}={solid,1pt}, there will be Z or 2?

Comment: @user1942348 Try to select texlive 2022 from the sidebar, it works fine in overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/cbqhgcsjcwft

Comment: @user1942348 The `Z` is a letter `Z` and means that there should be a line below the last row.

Comment: Okay ..........